# Grading many exams without getting sick

Tags: grading

I'm not sure if this question is on-topic here, but I imagine lots of people here deal with this problem.

In a few weeks, I'll have to grade about 500 exams. I'll receive them in paper form, and I need to give out the grades fairly quickly.

The last time I did this, I got the worst cold of my life and was totally incapacitated for the next week. What precautions can I take to make sure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid catching a cold? This has nothing to do with academia.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about academia. (Also see [boat programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about))

Comment: Try to stay out of crowded places for two weeks before you have to do the grading. Wash your hands frequently.

Comment: If you have some reason to believe the grading actually caused your illness, as opposed to simply happening at the same time, then please edit your question to reflect why and ti may be able to be reopened.

Answer (score 6):

Wear a surgical mask and nitrile or latex gloves. Do not touch your face while working. Take frequent breaks to walk away from the pile.

Comment: And get adequate sleep.